# Bash Loop Through URLs Issue

Tags: bash, curl

I'm using cURL request to google safe browsing API to check for any of my requested site is malicious or not. When i'm issuing the following command

```
$curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d ' { "client": { "clientId": "Test", "clientVersion": "1.0.0" }, "threatInfo": { "threatTypes": ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING","THREAT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED","UNWANTED_SOFTWARE","POTENTIALLY_HARMFUL_APPLICATION"], "platformTypes": ["WINDOWS","PLATFORM_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED","ANY_PLATFORM"], "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"], "threatEntries": [ {"url":"hxxp://bookmyroom.pk/assets/timepicker/f.exe"} ] } }' https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=AIzaSyD1IMgjaHEza6e9m_jwtjBgPmJX0IMKKIs

Caution: I have "xx"ed instead "tt" for the http string. This site might be a potential malicious site.So do not open it using browser.
```

I'm getting JSON response as

```
{
  "matches": [
    {
      "threatType": "UNWANTED_SOFTWARE",
      "platformType": "ANY_PLATFORM",
      "threat": {
        "url": "hxxp://bookmyroom.pk/assets/timepicker/f.exe"
      },
      "cacheDuration": "300.000s",
      "threatEntryType": "URL"
    }
  ]
}

Caution: I have "xx"ed instead "tt" for the http string. This site might be a potential malicious site.So do not open it using browser.
```

When i'm doing the same in loop

```
#check.sh

for i in $(cat malsite.txt); do
        content="$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d ' { "client": { "clientId": "Test", "clientVersion": "1.0.0" }, "threatInfo": { "threatTypes": ["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING","THREAT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED","UNWANTED_SOFTWARE","POTENTIALLY_HARMFUL_APPLICATION"], "platformTypes": ["WINDOWS","PLATFORM_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED","ANY_PLATFORM"], "threatEntryTypes": ["URL"], "threatEntries": [ {"url":"$i"} ] } }' https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key=AIzaSyD1IMgjaHEza6e9m_jwtjBgPmJX0IMKKIs)"
        echo "$i"
        echo "$content"
done

#malsite.txt

"hxxp://bookmyroom.pk/assets/timepicker/f.exe"

Caution: I have "xx"ed instead "tt"ing for the http string.This site might be a potential malicious site.So do not open it using browser.
```

I'm not getting any results. It just returns empty result.

```
#Result of /.check.sh :
{}
```

Not sure , Where i'm making mistakes. Any thoughts ?

Comment: The variable `$i` does not get expanded inside single quotes.

Comment: redned : Oh yes. Thanks ! Height of stupidity ! It works now !

Comment: Read [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to read your URLs from a file.

Comment: @chepner Thank you. Will do